# Editing the default meeting time

Tags: group-policy, outlook

Does anyone know how to edit the default meeting time via GP for Office 2010 ?

I've looked everywhere for this setting and cannot find it on any GP Admin Templates, we are looking to make the default meeting time 15 minutes opposed to the current 30 -  I realize there are 3rd party products which can do this, or can be done in VB but ideally I would have something which can be done via GP.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean the meeting `duration`?

Comment: If you're indeed talking about default duration that's entered when you make a new appointment, there's no default - it's determined by the duration of the last thing you had selected before clicking new. For example, if you had another appointment selected, the duration will match that appointment. If you just double click a time slot, it will match the time scale for the slot you clicked. You can change the default time scale, but that's about the closest you're going to get,

Comment: hi joeqwerty, thanks for the reply - I am indeed talking about the default duration, so from what you are saying I need to ask how I can change the time slot to 15 minute increments ? Thanks Again

Comment: Anyone else able to help here, I've spent so much time trying to figure this out! :)